# How to fix javascript pop-up "Window popup is already registered in the DOM!"?

Tags: javascript, dom, prototype

I am having problem on my window pop-up always says:
"Window popup is already registered in the DOM! Make sure you use setDestroyOnClose() or destroyOnClose: true in the constructor"

I already read other forums but I haven't find a solution on my problem.

```
 <script>   
     var win1 = null;
                function openPopupProduct(width,height,image1, image2, image3,image4, header) {
                    if(win1==null){
                        win1 = new Window('popup', {className: "alphacube", maximizable:false, minimizable:false, showEffectOptions: {duration:0.2}, hideEffectOptions: {duration:0.2} } ); 
                        }
                        width = width+150;
                        height = height+150;
                        newHTML = '<div class="noborder_preview" style="width:'+  width +'px;height:'+ height +'px">';
                        newHTML = newHTML + '<div class="preview_temp_load">';
                        newHTML = newHTML + header + '<br />';
                        newHTML = newHTML + '<img src="' + image1 + '" border="0">';

                        if(image2 != '') {
                            newHTML = newHTML + '&nbsp;<img src="' + image2 + '" border="0">';
                        }

                        if(image3 != '') {
                            newHTML = newHTML + '&nbsp;<img src="' + image3 + '" border="0">';
                        }

                        if(image4 != '') {
                            newHTML = newHTML + '&nbsp;<img src="' + image4 + '" border="0">';
                        }

                        newHTML = newHTML + '<\/div>';
                        newHTML = newHTML + '<\/div>';
                        win1.getContent().update(newHTML);
                        win1.setSize(width,height);
                        win1.showCenter();
                }
    </script>
```

I hope some one can help me on this.

Thank you in advnace.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem so  I open the Internet with a safari browser instead of Internet explorer and it open the web page fine , so just tried to open with another browser besides Internet explorer! You may have to install it yourself is the only thing , Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

The command **new Window** , in my case runs the code below

So do not use this command with JQuery, its always get error

ref: [JQuery and prototype](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

```
id = "window_" + new Date().getTime();
if ($(id))
        alert("Window " + id + " is already registered in the DOM! Make sure you use setDestroyOnClose() or destroyOnClose: true in the constructor");
```